# How to create a Google maps-like toolbar in android?

Tags: android

I'm especially interested in the left button(with pin icon).

[image]

Comment: Text Input Layout and Text Input Edit Text components, check this [link](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I was able to create the above output using the following code snippet.

`drawable\rounded_shape.xml`

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

    <solid
        android:color="#ee9595" >
    </solid>

    <padding
        android:left="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp" >
    </padding>

    <corners
        android:radius="50dp">
    </corners>

</shape>
```

And in your layout file add the following.

```
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:src="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:src="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn1"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"
        android:hint="Search Here">
    </EditText>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:src="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please make sure to change the `src` attributes in the `ImageButton` with your icons.